# How to print string as a ListView

Tags: java, android, json, listview, textview

I am new to all this android programming. After following a few tutorials I succesfully parsed a JSON url. Basicly, what I want to do is to print the string that I get in the end (ipString) as a textview or listview.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d("Rami","Rami");
    DefaultHttpClient   httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://jsonip.com");
    // Depends on your web service
    httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = null;
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);           
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        inputStream = entity.getContent();
        // json is UTF-8 by default
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");

        }
        result = sb.toString();
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
        String ipString = jObject.getString("ip");
        Log.d("ip", ipString);
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        // Oops
    }
    finally {
        try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
    }




}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}
From there, what am i supposed to do?

Thanks

Comment: you didnt parse anything, all you got was the raw string that was sent to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**: The "json" returned by the URL **http://jsonip.com** is invalid (according to testing on http://jsonlint.com/).

It shows this:

```
{
    ip: "216.49.181.254",
    about: "/about",
    Pro!: "http://getjsonip.com"
}
```

And should actually be something like this:

```
{
    "ip": "216.49.181.254",
    "about": "/about",
    "Pro!": "http://getjsonip.com"
}
```

To simplify your JSON fetch from the web, I would recommend looking at [AndroidQuery](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/AsyncAPI) (**AQuery**). It has a simple JSON call, which allows you to print out the result, or iterate through the results when it returns.

With this **AQuery** library, you can also fetch the JSON synchronously, if you are within an AsyncTask already.

Here is some example code of fetching the JSON:

```
public void asyncJson(){

    //perform a Google search in just a few lines of code

    String url = "http://www.google.com/somesearch";             
    aq.ajax(url, JSONObject.class, this, "jsonCallback");

}

public void jsonCallback(String url, JSONObject json, AjaxStatus status){

    if( json != null ){
        //successful ajax call

        String ipString = "";

        try {
            ipString = json.getString("ip");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d("ip", ipString);//do this if you just want to log the ipString

        //or, do this to set the "ip" string into a TextView 
        //referenced by "R.id.mytextview"
        aq.id(R.id.mytextview).text(ipString); //this is shorthand AQuery syntax
    } else {          
        //ajax error
    }

}
```

Comment: Using AQuery, you don't need to worry about HttpClient, HttpResponse, InputStream, BufferedReader, etc. And, if you are in the UI thread, it handles the async portion for you.